# How do I make the client directly download an mp3 file without extension

Tags: php, download, mp3

I have this link which is an mp3 but without the mp3 extension.

> http://p1.bcbits.com/download/track/65603e4f3638a532d575a1e76370fb19/mp3-128/1664686950?fsig=ab643a42a66fee7682a248039c38933e&id=1664686950&stream=1&ts=1443988800.0&e=1443988860&rs=32&ri=960&h=8275a4e4329c50d2bdb73f82ba337e73

I want to make the client download it but I'm getting an error written inside my file.

---

I found this code to make the client download the file:

```
<?php
$file_url = "http://p1.bcbits.com/download/track/65603e4f3638a532d575a1e76370fb19/mp3-128/1664686950?fsig=ab643a42a66fee7682a248039c38933e&id=1664686950&stream=1&ts=1443988800.0&e=1443988860&rs=32&ri=960&h=8275a4e4329c50d2bdb73f82ba337e73";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
```

And this is the error inside the downloaded file when I open it with a text editor:

```
Warning: readfile(http://p1.bcbits.com/download/track/65603e4f3638a532d575a1e76370fb19/mp3-128/1664686950?fsig=ab643a42a66fee7682a248039c38933e): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
in /customers/6/7/9/florens.be/httpd.www/DownloadMP3/DownloadMP3.php on line 6
```

The downloaded file has the name `1664686950?fsig=ab643a42a66fee7682a248039c38933e`

Comment: The server rejected your PHP-script internal download request. If you don't have permission to access it, then that's it. Serve local files, not remote URLs, and in particular not stuff from other websites.

Comment: Er... well, it seems that you have an error in the code, the first part would be $file_url = "htt... (with double quotes at the begining). But I suppose that this is not the problem

Comment: The second question might be: do the & mean anything in php in the middle of a string?? if the answer would be yes, then you might have a problem because you must escape those ampersands.

Comment: @mario So why can't my php script access it but I can on my PC?

Comment: @RaulLuna I accidentally deleted it while making this post. Nothing important. I changed it now.

Comment: @RaulLuna What do you mean with: you must escape those ampersands?

Comment: Lots of reasons. You're not letting on where the link originates. And nobody else can guess. Consult whoever hosts the files. If you don't have permission to download/stream it elsewhere, then don't. There's no magic code fix to make it work.

Comment: I mean that (probably) you have to convert those & to \&, but I am not an expert in php, please take what I am saying with caution